# Multiplying a scaler to a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, range, multiplication

I am given

```
>>> scalar = 3
>>> A = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
>>> D = []
```

What I am supposed to do is multiply all of A with the scaler and have that answer stored as D. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy.

```
>>> a = np.identity(3)
>>> a
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
>>> D = a * 3
>>> D
array([[3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3.]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For matrices you are better of by using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

scalar = 3
A = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
D = scalar * A
```

`print(D)` then returns

```
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

or, if you need Python lists again, use `D.tolist()` which returns `[[3, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 3]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make A three times bigger, just do:

```
scalar = 3
A = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
D = scalar * A
# D = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

If you are trying to multiply the *elements* by three, either see the other answer, or try something like this:

```
scalar = 3
A = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
D = [[ele * scalar for ele in sub] for sub in A]
# D = [[3, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original array *was not* an identity; you could use basic scaling in numpy to do that as well...

```
import numpy as np
scalar = 3
A = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
numpyArray = np.array(A)
numpyArray = numpyArray*scalar
newArray = numpyArray.tolist()
print(*newArray)
```